# Object spread not giving desired results

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

```js
let me={
    name:"Shivendra",
    age:21
}


let you={
    name:"Neha",
    age:22
}


let mergeMeAndYou={
    ...me, ...you
}

console.log(mergeMeAndYou);
```

I am getting the output:`- { name: 'Neha', age: 22 }`

Now I was not expecting this. Can any one explain this result ? & how I will now get the merged object ? I am using node version 8.9.4.

Comment: When you spread object 'me' it has key {name, age} and when you spread object 'you' it has also same keys {name, age}. so it replace previous assigned value and replace with new one. as a result {"name": "Neha",  "age": 22}

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: This is ,the expected result , because the spread will merge identical keys , so in your case it'll get the the values of the 'you' object

Comment: You are 100 % correct @BooBerr'ita , thats y object spread was not working...foolish me..

Comment: Yes @Atiq you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by enclosing the object with `{` and `}`, like: `{...obj}`

```js
let me={
   name:"Shivendra",
   age:21
}


let you={
   name:"Neha",
   age:22
}

//Putting the me and you on an array.
let mergeMeAndYou = [
   {...me},{ ...you}
]

console.log(mergeMeAndYou);

//Putting the me and you on an object. 
let mergeMeAndYou2 = {
   me:{...me}, you:{ ...you}
}

console.log(mergeMeAndYou2);
```

**Note:** Based on how you want to combine the objects, you don't really need to *Spread* the objects. You can just:

```
let mergeMeAndYou = [me,you];

let mergeMeAndYou2 = {me:me, you:you}
```

Comment: Thanks i understand the soln, and you are right for this object spread is indeed not required

Comment: Yes, it is not required if you are just assigning (point by reference). If you are trying to clone the object, then you need the spread it. In `ECMAScript 2018`, that is one way to clone an object.

Comment: Happy to help @ShivendraGupta

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding what the object spread does. It lists the properties of each object into a new object. Where you do it with more than one object it merges the properties of the objects into a new object. If the same properties exist in multiple spread objects, the one from the later object wins. Are you expecting it to append objects into a new parent structure? Or what did you expect to see?

If you want the objects placed into a parent object, try this:

```
const us = { me, you }
```

Or a parent array:

```
const we = [ me, you ]
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but i got the error , unexpected toxen {

Comment: If you already have defined object variables `me` and `you` as your code showed, and Node 8.9.4, then my code placed after yours should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

See the results. mergeMeAndYou function replace 'me' object by 'you' and mergeYouAndMe function replace 'you' object by me

```js
let me={
    name:"Shivendra",
    age:21
}


let you={
    name:"Neha",
    age:22
}


let mergeMeAndYou={
    ...me, ...you
}

let mergeYouAndMe={
    ...you, ...me
}

console.log(mergeMeAndYou);

console.log(mergeYouAndMe);
```

Comment: Yes thats right but its not that i want , i actually wanted to merge the object.

Comment: can you provide the desire results you think of? It would help us to understand what you actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The spread syntax in object literals copies object properties onto a new object.

From the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

> The Rest/Spread Properties for ECMAScript proposal (stage 4) adds spread properties to object literals. It copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto a new object.

And the provided example is as follows:

```
var obj1 = { foo: 'bar', x: 42 };
var obj2 = { foo: 'baz', y: 13 };

var clonedObj = { ...obj1 };
// Object { foo: "bar", x: 42 }

var mergedObj = { ...obj1, ...obj2 };
// Object { foo: "baz", x: 42, y: 13 }
```